# 7 pin s video and 4 pin s video compatibility

Tags: video-capture, s-video

I'm trying to connect my graphics card to a video capture card. My graphics card appears to have a 7 pin S Video connector and my capture card a 4 Pin.

The video card is a Sapphire HD 2600 Pro AGP, the blue one with VGA, DVI and S-Video found on [this](http://www.vgamuseum.info/index.php/component/k2/item/652-ati-radeon-hd-2600-pro) page and this image:
[image]

The capture card is a Dazzle DVC100 white found on [this](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/en/products/dazzle/dvd-recorder-hd/) page and this image:
[image]

My question is, if I get a cheap 4 Pin to 4 Pin S-Video cable, will it work with the 7 pin S-Video connector on my graphics card, simply ignoring the unused pins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it IS compatible looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video) page on Wikipedia, scrolling down to 7 pin S-Video.